# Synonyms of "that's it"

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I often use *that's it from me for today* to summarise and finish my report on daily standup.

Are there any other, similar phrases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Over and out.

This phrase comes from radio communication; it signifies that your statement is complete ("over") and that you are leaving the conversation ("out").  Many people who've never actually used a two-way radio will still recognize the phrase, and it's often used for humorous effect.

It can also be shortened to

> Anatoli out.

By the way - I presume that "daily standup" refers to a standup comedy routine.  If I'm wrrong about that, my answers may be inappropriate...

You could always fall back on the classics:

> [That's all, folks!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBzJGckMYO4)

or Forrest Gump:

> [That's all I have to say about that.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Otm4RusESNU)

Comment: It may be a daily [stand-up meeting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-up_meeting), a quick status report from team members that's often used as part of an Agile software development method. (The answers *over and out* or *That's all, folks* would be perfectly appropriate if the communication isn't so face-to-face - for example, I would feel comfortable using them in my status meetings held by phone or chat - but I think I'm more likely to use something simple like *That's everything.*)

Comment: In that case, I might be a little more reluctant to break out my best Porky Pig or Forrest Gump impression...

Comment: I agree with @aedia that all these variations seem a bit "flip" and unprofessional in the context of a work-based status report meeting.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative might be something like:

> Nothing else to report ...

or

> That brings today's report to an end ...

Answer (score 4):

If I were to live in the world of textbooks rather than the real world, I would always say **that's all**.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything wrong with just saying **That's it from me** every day, but if OP wants to ring the changes he could alternate with **I'm done**.

I used to participate in regular "conference calls" with maybe 2-6 co-workers. When it seemed we'd covered everything, whoever was notionally in charge would normally go through all our names to check we had nothing else to bring up. The standard reply was **I'm done**, before hanging up.

Answer (score 3):

*Let's call it a day* is sometimes heard in BrEng.

Comment: A daily standup is a quick status update meeting where all participants stand up, to encourage a quick update. Usually these meetings are in the morning, and others will give their updates after you, so *Let's call it a day* isn't appropriate in this situation. *That's it from me for today* in the question is really shorthand for *that's it from me for in today's meeting*.

Comment: @Hugo: Yes, quite right. Mine would be said only at the end of the day.

Comment: More to the point, only the *last* person to give his daily report could reasonably say this. And if that person isn't the boss, the actual boss might well feel his authority was being undermined anyway.

Answer (score -1):

This is [your name] signing off. Over and Out.

I've actually used this once and the teacher gave me heaps of marks.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective.